# SQL Server OUTPUT clause does not even return a NULL when no data inserted?

Tags: sql-server

When NO data was inserted, I would like @docId to be 0. I can't seem to make this work. I tried using MAX and/or COALESCE, but no success. What am I missing ? (It works fine when data is actually inserted).

```
DECLARE @NewDoc TABLE(DocId int)

INSERT INTO someTable
OUTPUT inserted.DocID INTO @NewDoc
SELECT some Fields
    FROM dbo.Documents d
    WHERE some conditions
PRINT 'Docs created: ' + cast( @@rowcount as char(10));

--save newly created docId into variable
select @DocId = COALESCE(DocId,0) from @NewDoc

--do more stuff using @DocId

--return @docId at end of storedProc
SELECT @docId Result
```

Comment: can you explain this line `I would like @NewDoc to be 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since when there is no data in `@NewDoc` the `@DocID` remains `null` you need to change it to

```
select @DocId = DocId from @NewDoc

if (@docID is null)
  set @docID = 0
```

Comment: I cannot accept this before a few minutes, but looks perfect, Thx.

Comment: @iDevlop I appreciate your attitude to ask something tricky to teach newbies that I am sure you already know ;)